# How to set limit values textbox and show message box when reached maximum limit VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Sorry for bad english.

I'm beginner in VB.Net, on this question I want to make textbox validation to show messagebox when maximum limit is reached.
below this code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim i As Integer
        TextBox1.MaxLength = 6
        i = TextBox1.MaxLength

        If TextBox1.Text.Length > i Then
            MsgBox("Maximum is 6 Character")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you set the MaxLength property you cannot use this event because your text will never be more that 6 characters. It is the control itself that doesn't accept any input after the 6th character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form load event set `TextBox1.MaxLength = 6`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      TextBox1.MaxLength = 6
 End Sub
```

and use the following code in  `TextBox1_KeyDown` *event*

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object _
                             , ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs _
                             ) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If Trim(TextBox1.Text).Length = 6 Then
        MsgBox("Maximum is 6 Character")
    End If
End Sub
```

Or

Keep `TextBox1.MaxLength` as system default,if you use below code then no need to alter it's lenghth to `6`

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If Trim(TextBox1.Text).Length = 6 Then
            e.Handled = True
            MsgBox("Maximum is 6 Character")
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the Load event?  I thought that was anti-pattern.  Why not the constructor or the OnLoad event?

Comment: It's work well, thank you very much for your answer.